# Trying to move from one JSP folder to another JSP folder in spring boot by using spring form tag library

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, spring-form

Well i am developing a spring boot application and for UI page designing i am using spring form tag library. In index.jsp there is a link "All Contacts". My requirement is when i click the Link All contact i want to move to "viewContact.jsp" page. but i am getting an Error.

Please comment and help me how to resolve this issues?

## index.jsp

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/submit" modelAttribute="contact"  >
        <table align="center" cellpadding="10"  cellspacing="10"
 bgcolor="#98AFC7">
            <tr>
                <td>Contact Name</td>
                <td><form:input type="text" path="name"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Contact Email</td>
                <td><form:input type="text" path="email"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Contact Number</td>
                <td><form:input type="text" path="num"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Register"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td><a href="viewAll">All Contacts</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form:form>
```

## viewContact.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>View Contacts Form</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#BCC6CC">
    <h1 align="center">View Contact Form</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Contact Name</th>
            <th>Contact Email</th>
            <th>Contact Number</th>
            
        </tr>
        
        <c:forEach items="contact" var="contact">
            <tr>
                <td>${contact.name}</td>
                <td>${contact.email}</td>
                <td>${contact.cnum}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
    
</body>
</html>
```

## contactInfoController.java

```
@GetMapping("/viewAll")
public String handleviewallContactDtlsLink(Model model) {
    List<Contact> allContacts = contactservice.getAllContacts();
    model.addAttribute("contact", allContacts);
    return "viewContact";

}
```

## Error page

[image]

Comment: its giving you `404` error .Make sure path is right .Also , `items="contact"` should be `items="${contact}"`

Comment: Thank you swati.I already resolved the issues.